# Is there a command that fills blocks based on biome? Or a mod that visualizes the boundaries?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I am trying to visualize some biomes in my single player world.

Once there were mods helping with this task, but none I can find works with 1.19 and above.

Is there a command or a mod that helps visualizing the biome boundaries?
I am particularly interested in the y-level variations of the biome boundaries.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of looking around it seems that the best there is around is [MiniHud](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/minihud), in particular, in the "Renderers" section of the options, the 3rd from the top "overlayBiomeBorder" when active shows the 3D biome border for a few layers around the player position.